# I am trying to use Neural Networks for regression on boston dataset using tensorflow. Somehow I am getting all predictions as wrong

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am  getting correct_eval as 0. I have used boston dataset. Splitted into training and testing. Used tensorflow for training the model. (Not keras). The neural networks consists of 2 hidden layers of size 13 each and input size is also 13.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data=pd.read_csv("Boston_Housing.csv")

x=data.iloc[:,0:13]
x=np.array(x)
y=data.iloc[:,13]
y=np.array(y)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y)


import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__

input_width=13;
num_layers=2
n_hidden_layer1=13
n_hidden_layer2=13
n_op=1

weights={
    "w_h1":tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([input_width,n_hidden_layer1])),
    "w_h2":tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_layer1,n_hidden_layer2])),
    "w_op":tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_layer2,n_op]))
}
biases={
    "b_h1":tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_layer1])),
    "b_h2":tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_layer2])),
    "b_op":tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_op]))
}

tf.trainable_variables()

def forwardPropagation(x,weights,biases):
    ip_h1=tf.add(tf.matmul(x,weights['w_h1']),biases['b_h1'])
    op_h1=tf.nn.relu(ip_h1)  
    ip_h2=tf.add(tf.matmul(op_h1,weights['w_h2']),biases['b_h2'])
    op_h2=tf.nn.relu(ip_h2)
    ip_op=tf.add(tf.matmul(op_h2,weights['w_op']),biases['b_op'])
    op_op=tf.nn.relu(ip_op)
    return op_op

s=tf.Session()
s.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
x=tf.placeholder("float",[None,input_width])
y=tf.placeholder("float",[None,n_op])
pred=forwardPropagation(x,weights,biases)

correct_pred=tf.equal(pred,y_train)
pred_eval,correct_eval=s.run([pred,correct_pred],feed_dict={x:x_train,y:y_train})
pred_eval,correct_eval

correct_eval.sum()
correct_eval
```

correct_eval is 0. Which means no prediction is correct. pred values are mostly 0 or completely random. kindly help me resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this line of code:

```
correct_pred=tf.equal(pred,y_train)
```

You are evaluating outputs from an untrained regression model using equality. There are a couple problems with this.

1. The values in `y_train` are produced by 3 layers that have random weights and biases. Each layer transforms the inputs using completely random transformations. Before you train your model on the dataset, the values in `y_train` will be very different from the values in `pred`.
2. `pred` and `y_train` both contain continuous values. It is almost always a bad idea to check for absolute equality between two continuous values because they need to be *exactly* the same values for the equality to be `True`. Say that you have trained your model, and the outputs in `pred` match the values in `y_train` very closely. Unless they *exactly* match up to the last significant digit, the comparison will always be `False`. Therefore, you always get `correct_eval=0`.

Most probably, you will want to calculate a metric like the mean square error (MSE) between `pred` and `y_train`. [tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/MeanSquaredError) is the common way to calculate the MSE in Tensorflow 2.0.

As for this,

> pred values are mostly 0 or completely random.

You are passing the outputs from the last layer through a ReLU function, which returns 0 for all negative inputs. Again, since the network's outputs come from random transformations, the outputs are random values with zeros in place of negative values. This is expected, and you will need to train your network for it to give any meaningful outputs.

It also looks like you are using Tensorflow 1.x, in which case you can use [tf.losses.mean_squared_error](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/losses/mean_squared_error).

Good luck!